# How To Measure The Performance Of Map Function In Tensorflow's New DataSet API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I've been using Tensorflow version 1.12 in my GPU instance, I have around 130 TfRecords file containing the ImageNet data which is  1.2 million. First I apply a map function and then `flat_map` to augment the dataset, which will ultimately be 1.2 million x 2048 images.

```
self.filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
self.eval_filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape = [None])
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.filenames)
eval_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.eval_filenames)
print("inside dataset ", dataset.output_shapes)
dataset = dataset.map(self.decode, num_parallel_calls=10)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(self.apply_flip_crop)
dataset = dataset.batch(self.config["batch_size"])
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

Here decode function returns the flattened array of the image and the one-hot encoded label. However, the function passed in `flat_map` does quite a heavy thing, which is like: two loops to create the slices and reverse of them each producing 1024 tensors. The final output for a single image would be the `[2048, 224, 224, 3]` tensor. The function looks like this:

```
   def apply_flip_crop(self, tf_example, lable):
        """
        Calls a helper function random_crop flips which randomly crops and flips
        the images, and returns the agumented tensors.

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param tf_example: A tensor of shape [batchsize, flattedimageshape]
        :type tf_example: Tensors [batchsize, flattedimageshape]
        :param lable: A Constant integer representing the class_id of the image.
        :type lable: tf.int32
        :return: Tensors of shape [flattedimageshape], label of image tf.int32
        :rtype: Tensors

        """

        data = tf.reshape(tf_example, [256, 256, 3])
        data = self.random_crop_flip(data)
        lables = [lable for i in range(2048)]
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, lables))


    def random_crop_flip(self, image):
        """
        Apply random crop and random flip to the image tensor.

        Parameters
        ----------
        :param image: A tensor representing a flattened image array.
        :type image: Tensor of shape [imageflattenedarray]
        :return: List of 2048 tensors of shape [imageflattenedarray]
        :rtype: List

        """
        crops = []

        for i in range(256 - 224):
            for j in range(256 - 224):
                crop = tf.slice(image, [i, j, 0], [224, 224, 3])
                crop2 = tf.reverse(crop, axis=[1])
                crops.append(crop)
                crops.append(crop2)
        return crops
```

Now the problem is that the training process is very slow. I've read that `dataset.from_tensor_slices` is quite bad with this kind of need. But I think there are lots of things which can be improved here. For that I need to visualize the performance of each of this operation. Mainly of the `flat_map` function. 
I'm using RunTime Statistic of tensorflow like this:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={data_gen.filenames:
                                                      training_filenames},
                 options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
next_element = iterator.get_next()
for i in range(1):

     datapoint = sess.run(next_element, options=run_options, 
                run_metadata=run_metadata)

      summary_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
```

Which does logs the time taken to prepare the dataset, however it doesn't log the time taken to perform the `flat_map` operation, which is my concern here as I suspect, that is the place where the performance is lagging. 
[image]

I would appreciate your help regarding both the **Performance suggessation** as well as **the measurement of the time taken in flat_map function**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the TensorFlow's timeline: [HowTo profile TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d)